# TcxComboBox with multiple column

Tags: delphi, combobox, devexpress

Is it possible populate TcxComboBox with multiple value eg.

```
ID  NAME    DESCRIPTION
1   Audi    Audi desc
2   Bmw     Bmw desc
```

And on button click get  ID or NAME?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a TcxLookUpComboBox.  It is very simple to do but requires you to define an in-memory dataset to hold
the records you want the cxLookUpComboBox to list, unless you already have another dataset which contains the records you want to show in its drop-down list, in which case you can use that.  The example I'm going to show uses a TClientDataSet so that it is self-contained.
In the following, CDS1 is the TClientDataSet and DS1, a TDataSource whose dataset is CDS1:

```
uses cxLookUpDBGrid;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
  Field : TField;
  Column : TcxLookUpDBGridColumn; // needs cxLookUpDBGrid in Uses clause
begin
  Field := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  Field.FieldName := 'ID';
  Field.DataSet := CDS1;

  Field := TStringField.Create(Self);
  Field.FieldName := 'Name';
  Field.DataSet := CDS1;

  CDS1.CreateDataSet;

  CDS1.IndexFieldNames := 'ID';

  //  Next, populate the CDS with a few records
  CDS1.InsertRecord([1, 'Apple']);
  CDS1.InsertRecord([2, 'Pear']);
  CDS1.InsertRecord([3, 'Banana']);

  CDS1.First;

  cxLookUpComboBox1.Properties.KeyFieldNames := 'ID';
  cxLookUpComboBox1.Properties.ListFieldNames := 'ID;Name';
  cxLookUpComboBox1.Properties.ListSource := DS1;
  cxLookUpComboBox1.Properties.ListFieldIndex := 2;  // returns Name value
  cxLookUpComboBox1.Properties.KeyFieldNames := 'ID';

  //  Next, add 2 columns to cxLookUpComboBox1 drop-down list

  Column := cxLookUpComboBox1.Properties.ListColumns.Add;
  Column.FieldName := 'ID';

  Column := cxLookUpComboBox1.Properties.ListColumns.Add;
  Column.FieldName := 'Name';

end;
```

If you prefer, you can create the drop-down columns in the
Object Inspector, which you can find in the ListColumns under its Properties property.  As you
will see in the OI, it is highly configurable.

Note that when the drop-down closes, the value which is returned is the field designated by the ListFieldIndex property.

[image]

Comment: Tnx for answer, Is it possible populate without TClientDataSet. I have TDataSource which DataSet is query. When set on TcxLookUpComboBox   https://ibb.co/xCP4rFY   TcxLookUpComboBox    is empty! My query return records.

Comment: Yes, it need not be a TClientDataSet, I just used that so the answer would be self-contained.  If your's isn't displaying any rows in the drop-down, most likely you omitted to configure the control's ListSource property.  In my answer, I suggested doing that in the Object Inspector, but I'll see if I can add some code to do it.

Comment: @user_odoo To populate a ClientDataset with the result of a query, you just have to add a TDatasetProvider component, this DatasetProvider needs to be linked to your Dataset with the DatasetProperty, and the ClientDataset needs to be linked to the DatasetProvider with the Provider Property. Now you just have to call the .Open method on the ClientDataset to populate it with the result of your query.

Comment: I've updated the answer so that the drop-down columns are defined in code.  @MarcGuillot:  Many thanks for pointing out about using  a DSP.

Comment: `ListFieldIndex` property determines which field is displayed as text.